# Wordpress - remove <figure class="wp-block-table">

Tags: wordpress, figure, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm struggling with tables in WP. When I make table, it's nested in figure tag with class "wp-block-table". How is it possible to remove class, or even better tag with class? I guess by using some filter... It's not so important, but it's irritating :).  Thanks for reply!

```
<div>
    <figure class="wp-block-table">
    <table></table>
    </figure>
 </div>
```

And I want this

```
 <div>
    <figure>
    <table></table>
    </figure>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's vital that you remove those classes from that `div > figure > table` structure, you can probably rig up some javascript to do it after the page loads.

But, with respect, it's really wierd to *remove* classes from HTML elements. The point of having classes on those elements is to make it possible for your theme's CSS to do a decent job of rendering them.

There are surely css rules looking something like this:

```css
div > figure.wp_block-table > table {
  attr: value;
  attr: value;
}
```

Right click / Inspect and you'll see it in devtools.

If you want to render your figures some special way, you can do that.
It's possible to *add* a class to a block like the table block. It's under Advanced in the right-side stuff about the block.

Then you can use Appearance / Custom CSS Rules to tweak out your rendering so it's perfect.